# FirabaseAuth can't catch exception in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a signup screen for my app. I implemented firebase and can authenticate user and save some user info into firebase database succesfully. I started to check if userName field is empty or not. But firebase sometimes can not catch exception about bad formatted email address. It works for password (min 6 char) everytime but sometimes work for email. I can't find any solution. Here is my code. Is there anybody who have an idea?

```
 onPressed: () async {
    if (validateName(userName) && validateEmail(email)) {
      setState(() {
        showSpinner = true;
      });
      try {
        final newUser =
            await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: email, password: password);
        if (newUser != null) {
          //get name and update user profile
          UserUpdateInfo userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
          userUpdateInfo.displayName = userName;
          FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
          await user.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
          await user.reload();

          Navigator.pushNamed(context, NavigationScreen.id);
        }
        setState(() {
          showSpinner = false;
        });
      } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        setState(() {
          showSpinner = false;
        });
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: e.message,
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 3,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          textColor: Colors.red,
          fontSize: 18.0,
        );
      }
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: 'You must ente all information',
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 3,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        textColor: Colors.red,
        fontSize: 18.0,
      );
    }
  },

//name TextField validation
  bool validateName(String name) {
    if (name != null && name.length > 2) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  //email TextField validation
  bool validateEmail(String email) {
    if (email != null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createUserWithEmailAndPassword` returns a `Future<AuthResult>`, to catch the error you can do the following:

```
final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password).catchError((err) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Error"),
              content: Text(err.message),
              actions: [
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Ok"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          });
```

Using [`catchError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-async/Future/catchError.html), it will handles errors emitted by this Future, and then `showDialog` will display a dialog with the error.

Comment: this is a work around, thanks. But I stil dont understand why it can't catch the firebaseauth exception. Is there a bug?

Comment: No but createuserwithEmailAndPassword is asynchronous whenever you use asynchronous code it is better to call catcherror which is basically like catch but for async code

Comment: so you mean dont use try catch, instead use catchError for async code?

Comment: If it is an asynchronous operation yes, since catcherror will catch everything

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-async/Future/catchError.html

Comment: @wierdo Since the answer helped you please mark it as correct, thank you!